# Contrastive Stress

Tags: pronunciation

Could you tell me where the contrastive stress is ? I'm really confused about contrastive stress.
  A: Who's your favourite actress?
  B: I love Natalie Portman. How about you?

Comment: Hi, @Mohaddese, welcome to EL&U! Are you specifically wondering about B's question, or also about anywhere that contrastive stress could be used? Is this a question from a book or homework? What exactly confuses you? More information will let us give you better answers. Use the "edit" link just below your question to add more detail. For more about how to ask questions, see our [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). You might also be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you *contrast* two things, you are *comparing* them. To inject *contrastive stress* in the question is to emphasize that this question is about the comparison.

> How about *you*?

The subtext here would be:

> I expect your opinion may be different, so I am interested in hearing what you have to say on the matter.